# Display taxonomies for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type as `Products` with custom taxonomies `product-year` `product-cat` and `product-country`

I want to create a table like below but I am not sure how to populate the code.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your questions already been answered here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155637/display-custom-post-type-category-taxonomy

you should be able to use [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)